# Flask / Python: How call a function from another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to call the h_dws () function in the run.py file from h.dws.py from the holds folder.

run.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, get_flashed_messages, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from holds.h_dws import h_dws

app = Flask(__name__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/tkp/Desktop/uploads_files'
app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] = ['.csv']
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/')
def index():
    files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():
    id_group = request.form.get("id_group","")
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)

    if filename != '':       
        if id_group == "1":          
            print('1')            
        if id_group == "2":
            print('2')            
        if id_group == "3":  
            
            h_dws(uploaded_file)  

    return {"status": "OK"}
```

h_dws.py

```
import pandas as pd 

def h_dws(uploaded_file):
    
    uploaded_file.stream.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, index_col=False, sep=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    
    list_set = set(df['Col1'].tolist())
    unique_list = (list(list_set)) 

    good = []
    for i in unique_list:
        df2 = df[df.Col1.str.contains(i)]
        x = str(max(list(set(df2['Col2']))))
        df3 = df2[df2.Col2.astype(str).str.contains(x)]
        good.append(df3)

    finaldf = pd.concat(good)

    finaldf.to_csv('C:/Users/tkp/Desktop/uploads_files/'+filename, sep=';', header=True, index = False, float_format='%f')
    
    return finaldf
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="id_group"><input type="submit" value="Convert" name="id_group"></p>
    </form>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

folder structure:

[image]

Unfortunately I'm getting "Internal Server Error":
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined in h_dws.py

Do I have to import all the variables from run.py into h_dws.py?

Comment: This could be any exception in your code ... Don't you have any output/logs of the server ?

Comment: NameError: name 'filename' is not defined, in h_dws.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give the `filename` as a paramter to `h_dws(...)`

Try the following, where you call it:

```
h_dws(uploaded_file, filename)
```

And in h_dws.py in your method signature:

```
def h_dws(uploaded_file, filename):
```

The problem is that `filename` doesn't exist in the scope of `h_dws(...)`. You could read up on this topic for example [here](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#:%7E:text=Local%20(or%20function)%20scope%20is,you%20define%20inside%20the%20function.&text=If%20the%20local%20scope%20is,the%20outer%20or%20enclosing%20function.)